# How can I show that these menus are related to another?

Tags: navigation

I currently have the following navigation structure. Users have the option to manage multiple workspaces, and both the 'Company' and 'Jobs' pages are directly tied to a specific workspace. If you click at the workspaces dropdown, it will display a list with your workspaces, so you can click to select.

I want to emphasize the connection between these elements. Additionally, I'm uncertain about how to achieve this on mobile.

The another links (such as add users, dashboard, etc) on the right are independent.

[image]

Comment: What would be the initial state? I mean, what would users see before selecting any workspace? This is the most important info, because it looks like you can solve this with just a couple tabs, but without knowing the initial state it's just a guess

Comment: Users always is inside a workspace. The default is the most recently used.
I already have some tabs inside company and jobs. Updated the question with this image.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You could try it with a different information hierarchy. First the user needs to select the respective tab (Jobs or Company) and based on the selection the workspace is available.

Since we don't have more context i assume that by changing the tab the content of the page changes, but the links on the right side stay consistent. You can also think about keeping the header simple and include the Tab and dropdown in the content section. It depends on the context.

Be careful with the dropdown and follow common guidelines, like e.g. https://carbondesignsystem.com/components/dropdown/
It would be helpful to have here more context of the content inside the dropdown. If you have more than 10 menu items, i would recommend a combobox for easy findability.

For mobile i would put the links on the right side in a simple burger. Ofc you can optimize the size, but i would recommend to do some research about the accessibility of the burger.

Comment: thanks for the insights.  Im not sure because users first select a workspace.
the tab is a good choice in mobile but inside the page I already have a tab. Ive updated the question with this image.